# Using selenium java need to retrieve data from angularjs

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to retrieve data from the DB using angularjs to selenium java.

Below steps I tried but I couldn't retrieve data.

Use Selenium code---

**HTML page source**

```
`<div class="col-sm-6">
<input id="LastName" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" type="text" required="" ng-model="UserProfiles.LastName" name="LastName" placeholder="Please Enter Last Name"/>
</div>`
```

**Selenium Java code**

```
WebElement cityField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[ng-model='UserProfiles.FirstName']"));

cityField.clear();
cityField.sendKeys("Chicago");
System.out.println("Print- "+ cityField.getAttribute("input[ng-model='UserProfiles.FirstName"));

cityField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[ng-model='UserProfiles.LastName']"));
System.out.println("+++-- "+cityField.getText());`
```

Comment: What error did you get?  Where does it fail?

Comment: I'm not getting any output values ('System.out.println("+++-- "+cityField.getText());')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is attempting to get the text inside an "input" element, which will return nothing.  Please try

```
cityField.getAttribute("value")
```

Comment: cityField.getAttribute("UserProfiles.LastName");

Comment: No, try it just as I've entered it.  getAttribute() is getting the html attribute "value" of the web element cityField, which will be what's filled into the input control.

Answer (score 0):

**You can used a common function as:**

```
public String getAttributeValue(WebDriver driver, String locator, String attribute) {
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator));
    return element.getAttribute(attribute);
}
```

**In test script:**

```
String idValue = getAttributeValue(driver, "//input[@id='LastName']", "id");
String modelValue = getAttributeValue(driver, "//input[@id='LastName']", "ng-model");
String nameValue = getAttributeValue(driver, "//input[@id='LastName']", "name");
```

The same way for getText of an element.